# Temp Filename on specific partition?

Tags: .net, temporary-files

I know about `Path.GetTempFileName()` and how to get the temp folder (usually its on your C drive)

But how do i get a temp filename on a specific partition? i think as a workaround i'll do something like targetBaseDir/temp.tmp and then File.Move when its complete.

Comment: would you please explain more that what you exactly want to do?

Comment: @Beatles: They want to create a temporary file which they will write to to do a rename afterwards, to avoid clobbering a file that's already there on saving. Since you can only do an atomic move on a single volume (not a partition :-)) you can't make good use of `GetTempFileName()` which would use `$Env:Temp` as the location for the file. But the logic for creating a uniquely-named file if there are already some others might be helpful – that's why I think this question was asked.

Comment: @Johannes: Thank you for your answer. That was the same thing that I guessed but I wanted to be sure before I made any comment

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: Thats *exactly* my reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just create your own GetTempFilePath method?

Something like this

```
string GetTempFilePath(string basePath, string extension)
{
    return Path.Combine(basePath, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+"."+extension);
}

//Usage
GetTempFilePath("E:\\", "tmp");

//Output
//E:\e2e4873e-daf5-41b6-bdc5-2afec61921e2.tmp
```

Or you can use the native [GetTempFileName](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetTempFileName.html) method that is used by `System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()`

Comment: I would use `Path.GetRandomFileName` rather than `Guid.NewGuid`, but good answer otherwise ;)